# Why does my tab container box exceed my main div?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I really need your help with this. I have been at this for a few hours to no avail. So I am taking to the interwebs of gurus and experts.

Why does my .tab_container div exceed my main div on the right? How do you remedy this problem?

Here's a picture of the problem:
[image]

Here's a picture of the desired result:
[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS Markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.tab_wrapper {
    background: rgb(231,231,226);
    height: 100%;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="table-container">

    <div id="container">

        <div id="main" style="display: inline-block; border:1px solid red; width: 983px;">

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#tab1">XAL-2017-482336</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">A-2017-00471</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab_container">

                <div class="tab_wrapper"></div>

            </div>


        </div><!-- END DIV main -->         

    </div><!-- END DIV container -->

</div><!-- END DIV table-container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove the padding:3px in the tab container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .tab_container has padding property. It will add up to the value of the actual width, say for example you have a width of 200px and you've added padding to all sides with 3px, the final width would be actual width(200px) + padding(3px) = 203px.

If you wanted to add a padding on all your div containers without changing the desired width add this code in your css.

```
*, *:before, *:after{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See [working output](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/1848/) in jsfiddle